# How do you load a different page in WordPress

Tags: routing

I need to have a page display a different page depending on the content of a cookie.  I can do this using a 301 redirect, but it's slow.  I want to do it entirely within WordPress using a plugin if this is possible.

I do not want to cause a trip back to the browser. Keeping the original url is actually a positive effect in this case.

Comment: if speed is the concern then doing this means the page can't be cached as PHP needs to executed every time, so it could be much slower than a redirect to a cached page ( which could be implemented entirely in Apache/Nginx or even at the CDN level making it fast, JS in the browser could do it making it even faster )

Comment: Additionally, if your site is running HTTPS+HTTP/2 there may be no additional round trip, the browser can reuse the existing connection to request the redirected page

Comment: It's currently being done in JS in the browser and the client is fine with the performance.